# ¿Como puedo obtener el numero de compilación en android?

Tags: android

Hola alguien puede ayudarme?
Me gustaría obtener el numero de compilación de android, atraves de código, no se se si es posible

Comment: Hola Julio, para que obtengas mejores respuestas agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, recuerda realizar preguntas en base a [ask] ¿no te refieres a la versión te refieres al build number del dispositivo o de tu aplicación?

Comment: proba con Build.FINGERPRINT o Build.DISPLAY

Answer (score -3):

Para obtener la versión de Android, yo utilizo esta función. Te la paso tanto en Java como en Kotlin, dependiendo del lenguaje que utilices (ya que no queda especificado en tu comentario).

**Java**

```
public static String currentVersion(){
    double release=Double.parseDouble(Build.VERSION.RELEASE.replaceAll("(\\d+[.]\\d+)(.*)","$1"));
    String codeName="Unsupported";
    if(release>=4.1 && release<4.4)codeName="Jelly Bean";
    else if(release<5)codeName="Kit Kat";
    else if(release<6)codeName="Lollipop";
    else if(release<7)codeName="Marshmallow";
    else if(release<8)codeName="Nougat";
    else if(release<9)codeName="Oreo";
    else if(release<10) codeName = "Pie";
    else if(release<11) codeName = "Android 10";
    return codeName+" v"+release+", API Level: "+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
fun currentVersion(): String {
    val release = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(java.lang.String(Build.VERSION.RELEASE).replaceAll("(\\d+[.]\\d+)(.*)", "$1"))
    var codeName = "Unsupported"
    if (release >= 4.1 && release < 4.4)  codeName = "Jelly Bean"
    else if (release < 5) codeName = "Kit Kat"
    else if (release < 6) codeName = "Lollipop"
    else if (release < 7) codeName = "Marshmallow"
    else if (release < 8) codeName = "Nougat"
    else if (release < 9) codeName = "Oreo"
    else if (release < 10) codeName = "Pie"
    else if (release < 11) codeName = "Android 10"
    return codeName + " v" + release + ", API Level: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
}
```

Recuerda ir manteniendo el código conforme vayan apareciendo nuevas versiones. Las versiones más antiguas que la versión 4 ya no las tengo en cuenta...

Answer (score -4):

Para obtener el Version prueba con

```
 int myVersionApp = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
```

Aparte tienes estos otros datos que puedes obtener

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]